# Change button in listview with reference to data

Tags: sqlite, listview, button

i can speak english just little..
i made listview with sqlite db.
I want to implement this function

ex)

1. i have sqlite db (with listview. i made already. and listview have button)
   rowId 1, 2, 3
   number 0, 1, 0
2. i need like this

   if ( number == 0) {
   button.backgroundResource(R.drawble.icon1);
   } else if ( number == 1) {
   button.backgroundResource(R.drawble.icon2);
   }

Attached pictures for easier understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfiSS.jpg)

and this is my listadapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    public interface ListBtnClickListener {
        void onListBtnClick(int position, View view);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<SongList> mList, ListBtnClickListener clickListener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList = mList;
        this.listBtnClickListener = clickListener;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_item);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        _url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_url);
        _name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        _time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_time);
        _img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_thumbnail);
        favorite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mList.get(position).get_img(), 0, mList.get(position).get_img().length);
        _img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        final SongList listViewItem = mList.get(position);

        if (mList != null) {
            _url.setText(listViewItem.get_url());
            _name.setText(listViewItem.get_name());
            _time.setText(listViewItem.get_time());
        }

        final SongList songList = mList.get(position);

        favorite.setTag(position);

        favorite.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (this.listBtnClickListener != null) {
            this.listBtnClickListener.onListBtnClick((int) view.getTag(), view);

        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some method like `SongList.getNumber()`. You can change your code in if block like this:

```java
 if (mList != null) {
    _url.setText(listViewItem.get_url());
    _name.setText(listViewItem.get_name());
    _time.setText(listViewItem.get_time());

    // assuming you have getNumber() method
    int number = listViewItem.getNumber();
    
    // checking if number is equal to 0
    if(number == 0){
         favorite.backgroundResource(R.drawble.icon1);
    } else{
         favorite.backgroundResource(R.drawble.icon2);
    }
 }
```

**Edit:** If you are storing `number` variable for only changing the background of button, then you can just use `position` parameter provided in `getView()` method. All you have to do is check if `position` is even or odd and change the background of the button accordingly.

Comment: i shared my listadapter.. but i test alot. my code not clean.. i want you understand :).. thank you sir

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much sir. it's worked. that's easy. but i didint know. I will try to help others too like you.

Comment: You are welcome. If you please, can you mark my answer as correct?